# Equivalent of this two line Perl in Python?

Tags: python, perl

I need to find exact equivalent of this two line Perl in Python 2.x

**PERL:**

```
foreach my $edge (@edges){
    $edge =~ s/[\(\)]//g;
    my @verts = split(/,/, $edge);
```

**PYTHON:**

```
for edge in edges:
    edge = ???
    verts = ???
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what the perl does, this way, people that know python but do not know perl can help you.

Comment: edge is already set. You may need re.sub and re.split but idk what your input looks like so i cant really advise.

Comment: You should edit your original question and add the code there, comments don't allow line breaks. Some sample input and output would be useful too, along with an explanation of what the perl code is supposed to do. "I know about "lxq" and "lx" codes, problem is that 2 line! Thank you very much." << What do those two lines do?..

Comment: If you can give an example of an input and the resulting output I might be able to help you. Is "(000, 000)" an example of an input? Is it it a string? Or is it some other type? If it's an input, what would the corresponding output be?

Comment: @gnur: For Python coders who don't know Perl.

The first of the two lines is eliminating all '(' or ')' in edge (which is assumed to be a string) through regexp matching. To be clear, by eliminating I mean mutating the string.

The second line is splitting the remaining string on commas. So if the string was `a,b,c`, the array `@verts` will now have elements `a`, `b`, and `c`.

So if the full input is the string `(a,b,c,(d,(e,f)))`, the result would be an array with elements `a b c d e f`.

Comment: @Ndv See my comment above. As I explain what your two lines of Perl do, I can't help but feel like your solution to whatever higher level problem you're solving is very brittle. It is usually a good idea to include the big picture behind your low level question so that people can suggest alternate ways to solving your problem.

Comment: I quibble with the less-than-readable stripping of ()'s with `s/[\(\)]//g`.  Wouldn't `s/[()]//g` be sufficient, and more understandable, as parens should not be interpreted as grouping symbols inside of a [] character set?

Comment: @Ndv: Also, in your Full Perl code block, you have `@verts[0]` and `@verts[1]` where in Perl it should be `$verts[0]` and `$verts[1]` respectively. Note: I know `@verts[1]` will work for arrays, but not for hashes. You might as well standardize the way you access your structures.

Comment: [SPAM] yeah, we all love perl for it's complete illegibility ;] Beside this it has best regexp implementations I know :D

Comment: @Paul McGuire: or even `y/()//d`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
edge = edge.translate(None, '()')
verts = edge.split(',')
```

You might also want to convert strings to ints in creating verts, using:

```
verts = map(int, edge.split(','))
```

Comment: You could also use `edge.translate(None, '()')` to remove the brackets.

Comment: perl's split will omit trailing empty fields (e.g. `a,b,c,,,` will produce 3 elements, not 6)

Answer (score 4):

Using the regex module to stick closely to the Perl version:

```
for edge in edges:
    edge = re.sub( '[()]', '', edge )
    verts = filter( None, re.split( ',', edge ) )
```

At the top of the script make sure to include

```
import re
```

Comment: perl's split will omit trailing empty fields (e.g. `a,b,c,,,` will produce 3 elements, not 6)

Comment: @Ndv: Re: "YOU ARE THE MAN!!! THANK YOU VERY MUCH! :)"  ...and you should thank him by accepting an answer.

Comment: @ysth good catch, I've updated the code to remove empty results from the split

Answer (score 0):

use string methods `replace` ans `split` (or `sub` and `split` from `re` module). Generally, read about Regular Expressions - most modern languages implementations (int Python too) is based on Perls. And patterns in you're code are very simple:
first you removes all occurrences of '(' and ')', than split line by ',' (as I can tell, I haven't written in perl for years)